# Interacting with a command line password prompt

Tags: php, python, command-line

I am trying to use the command line tool pt-online-schema-change from php. I am passing in the user argument but the password for that user is requested by a prompt. I have tried using proc_open, listening for the prompt and replying with the password but i'm having little joy. The output pipe never seems to get the password prompt. I tried waiting a second then just inputting it but this didn't work either.

Right now i'd be extremely happy to see a working example of a call to the command line program that catches and successfully responds to a password prompt. I'd take that example in python or php as chances are this will end up being run in a cron.

I'd also accept any way of providing the script with the password beforehand. Details on pt-online-schema-change:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html

Comment: The documentation of `pt-online-schema-change` also describes the argument `--password`, why can't you use that one?

Comment: I ought to have said but i tried that without success. Thanks for the reply anyway, as you can probably tell by the huge delay in my checking this the question has become moot for me now anyway as we went with a totally different implementation.